# What is the point of the "/T" flag for taskkill?

Tags: windows, kill

`taskkill /?` says:

```
This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name.
```

Listing the flags, it goes:

```
/T                     Terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it.
```

??

Isn't that the whole point of the tool? If I don't use /T, it doesn't terminate the specified process? Or does it means that /T means "kill **also** child processes", which is not done without /T? It really couldn't be more cryptic and ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The description is apt and accurate. It does exactly as is said, the issue is likely in your understanding of threading/process management. A thread that is spawned by a process does not necessarily terminate prior to its parent, thus there may come a need to enforce termination via the `/T` flag.

For instance lets say I create a management interface for a long running task(Read as calling another .exe file from a main management service) that processes data. Its possible that the management interface does not need to run while the child thread is being completed, and indeed, this management interface might crash from time to time. I can choose to force kill my management interface, and leave the long running process unaffected (by default). Or, if I use the /T flag I can choose to end both processes, and start the data processing from fresh if desired.

Comment: You're confusing "threads" and "child processes". The question is not directly about [threads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads), it's about processes. Killing a process is exactly killing all its threads. You cannot kill a process without killing all its threads. You can however kill a process without killing its child processes (which are *different* than its threads) – this is what the question is about. Please edit the answer and fix the terminology. I'm willing to upvote the answer then, but no sooner.